# How do I dynamically populate a list with data from a JSON file at regular intravels in Spring boot. [@Schedule]

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

How do I dynamically populate a list with data from a JSON file at regular intervals in Spring boot.

I'm thinking it can be done using @Schedule.

Task: To create an api which performs some computations on data received from a json file and dynamically change the output as new data adds.

I've been able to create an api which takes in a POST request from Postman which in turn populates my List and performs the computation, but i need to automate this process using a file, which will dynamically get new data.

But could someone please highlight the exact procedure to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As @Scheduled is an asynchronous operation it won't produce output for rest response.

Here could be following ways to process JSON file.

1. You can define an endpoint to submit JSON file.
2. Do computations and store in DB and then return the response immediately. But in case JSON file processing takes a long time then you should do computations in a background thread and return "In Progress" response to the user.
3. Define a separate API for fetching the list of data collected through JSON.

Comment: Thanks you for the information Gaurav.
1. I have created an endpoint [POST request] where i submit Json.
2. Done.
3. Done.

Now how would i work through a procedure where it reads the submitted Json file after every few (30) seconds.